# Angular Creating Overlay

Tags: angular, angular6, overlay, angular-cdk

I am trying to create a custom Overlay however I keep getting the following Error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[OverlayRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OverlayRef]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for OverlayRef!
  at NullInjector.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.g t (core.js:8894)
  at resolveToken (core.js:9139)
  at tryResolveToken (core.js:9083)
  at StaticInjector.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8980)
  at resolveToken (core.js:9139)
  at tryResolveToken (core.js:9083)
  at StaticInjector.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8980)
  at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21120)
  at NgModuleRef_.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21809)
  at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:1772)
```

Now I am sure at first Glance it looks that I am missing the `OverlayModule` however it is imported.

I can import `Overlay` and `OverlayConfig` from @angular/cdk/overlay; without having any issues. However as soon as I add `OverlayRef` the error will appear.

The Angular Overlay Reference is found [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api)

I have not created an Overlay before so I am following [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/11/20/custom-overlays-with-angulars-cdk.html) guide by Thoughtram. The only difference is I do not create a separate service for handling the closing of an Overlay.

**Code Below:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OverlayHandlerService {

private readonly DEFAULT_CONFIG: OverlayHandlerDialogProperties = {
  hasBackdrop: true,
  backdropClass: 'dark-backdrop',
  panelClass: 'tm-file-preview-dialog-panel',
  scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.noop()
}

constructor(private overlay: Overlay, private overlayRef: OverlayRef) { 

}

private CreateOverlay(config: OverlayHandlerDialogProperties): OverlayRef {
  const _OVERLAY_COFIG = this.GetOverlayConfig(config);

  return this.overlay.create(_OVERLAY_COFIG);
}

private GetOverlayConfig(config: OverlayHandlerDialogProperties): 
  OverlayConfig {
    const _POSITION_STRATEGY = this.overlay.position()
    .global()
    .centerHorizontally()
    .centerVertically();

  const _OVERLAY_CONFIG = new OverlayConfig({
    hasBackdrop: config.hasBackdrop,
    backdropClass: config.backdropClass,
    panelClass: config.panelClass,
    scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block(),
    positionStrategy: _POSITION_STRATEGY
  });

  return _OVERLAY_CONFIG;
}

public OpenOverlay(overlayComponent: any, configurations?: 
OverlayHandlerDialogProperties): void {
    const _DIALOG_CONFIGURATIONS = { ...this.DEFAULT_CONFIG, ...configurations };
    const _OVERLAYREF = this.CreateOverlay(_DIALOG_CONFIGURATIONS);
    const _OVERLAYPORTAL = new ComponentPortal(overlayComponent);

    _OVERLAYREF.attach(_OVERLAYPORTAL);
 }

 public CloseOverlay(): void {
   this.overlayRef.dispose();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my Testing it seems you can not import both Overlay and OverlayRef in the same service, this will cause the error above.

You already have a reference to the overlay when you create it.

`this._Dialog_Reference = this.CreateOverlay(_DIALOG_CONFIGURATIONS);`

However if you returned a different class as per the example by Thoughtram you would have to import it through the constructor. In the Thoughtram example I think having a second class to return with dispose may be a bit too much if you are developing only for yourself or a project at work. If you were though going to publish a package then I would suggest following there example with returning a different class so that the developer using your package has less of a chance messing up.

Comment: overlayRef it's not "injectable", overlayRef should be a variable. You give value to the variable when use `this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create(...)`. You're using a const _OVERLAYREF=..., but if you use this, you can not "dispose" it